# Area ASP.NET MVC 4 strangely not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have a strange problem working with Areas in ASP.NET MVC 4.

```
root --- Areas --- Admin      ___ HomeController
                              ___ AgenceController
               --- AdminAgence___ HomeController
                              ___ AgenceController
```

The Admin Area works perfectly, now when I passed to the AgenceAdmin, it works when I redirect the Home Controller and not working when I redirect to AgenceController or any other Controller, this is my regestration code for both areas :

```
public class AdminAgenceAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get
            {
                return "AdminAgence";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "AdminAgence_default",
                "AdminAgence/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

And For the Admin Area (wich works perfectly)

```
public class AdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get
            {
                return "Admin";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Admin_default",
                "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

And the Global.asax.cs

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
        }
    }
```

I made the AdminAgence Area just like the Admin and nothing works for the AdminAgence ...

I also work with roles to define the role to access every area, and the roles area Admin, AdminAgence and Membre

Comment: Is there a home controller with an index action in the Agence area?

Comment: I don't know if it's a typeo but I'd start by making the `AdminAgence` and `AgenceAdmin` labels consistent.

Comment: @ericdc yes and the Admin Area works perfectly

Comment: @Jasen what do you mean by consistent ?

Comment: Make sure labels match for folders, route mappings, controller names, etc. In this post you use two versions -- which is correct?

Comment: no it is only one version, 2 areas one named Admin and the other named AdminAgence.

Comment: I just removed the area and created a new one :p and it works :p sorry guys that the story ended up this way :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to add anything.  Best is that you need to remove all that routing from your existing project that references your new area name, and then let the framework handle all of the routing for you.

Comment: I am really fed up that I tried to solve a problem that can be solved with such a ... native way :) it works :) thank you but I don't see why it didn't work :( is it a bug in ASP.NET ? I don't think so

Comment: Its been my experience that the native mvc api is very strict and should only be circumvented when there are exceptions to the rule.  There are many other flaky routing engines out there, or you can build your own.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `MapRoute` overload with `namespaces` in all your mappings

```
context.MapRoute(
    name: "AdminAgence_default",
    url: "AdminAgence/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new string[] { "MyNamespace.Areas.AdminAgence.Controllers" }
);
```

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Comment: I should tell you also that I use Roles, I don't know if this influences the route

Answer (score 1):

Check the area folder name to ensure it matches the route name specified in the code.

Comment: Yes It matches I just saw it

Comment: I should tell you also that I use Roles, I don't know if this influences the route